# Jolt - change format of elasticsearch response

Tags: elasticsearch, jolt

This should be a no brainer as Jolt was built mainly to transform ES ,mongodb responses.But I am unable to figure it out

I want to parse ES response and print only selected fields. For instance I want to transform the response to

```
{
"time" : 63,
"totalhits":100,
"0";{ response1.field1,response1.field2},
"1";{ response2.field1,response2.field2},
"2";{ response3.field1,response3.field2},
}


  {
  "took" : 63,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1000,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "bank",
      "_type" : "account",
      "_id" : "0",
      "sort": [0],
      "_score" : null,
      "_source" : {"account_number":0,"balance":16623,"firstname":"Bradshaw","lastname":"Mckenzie","age":29,"gender":"F","address":"244 Columbus Place","employer":"Euron","email":"bradshawmckenzie@euron.com","city":"Hobucken","state":"CO"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "bank",
      "_type" : "account",
      "_id" : "1",
      "sort": [1],
      "_score" : null,
      "_source" : {"account_number":1,"balance":39225,"firstname":"Amber","lastname":"Duke","age":32,"gender":"M","address":"880 Holmes Lane","employer":"Pyrami","email":"amberduke@pyrami.com","city":"Brogan","state":"IL"}
    }, ...
    ]
  }
    }
```

The spec file I got so far is

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "hits": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&"
        }
      }
    }
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

figured it out.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "took": "took",
      "hits": {
        "total": "total_hits",
        "hits": {
          "*": {
            "_source": {
              "country": "Response[&2].country",
              "city": "Response[&2].city",
              "year": "Response[&2].year"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```